# Can't log in to Concrete5 installation...get "Page Not Found" error

Tags: concrete5

A client just notified me that the login on their Concrete 5.5.2.1 site is no longer working, and I've confirmed it for myself (neither is the "forgot password" process). I don't know how long it's been like that, though, because it's been months since anyone tried to log in, and I don't know what they may have changed that is causing this.

When you attempt to log in, it doesn't simply fail...it redirects to the rather odd URL of "http://www.techwerks.tv/index.php/login/-/do_login/" and informs you "Page Not Found...No page could be found at this address." Attempting to recover your password gives you a similar result.

It seems that the login script is trying to call a file which it can't find or is corrupted, but I don't know what that file is, and posting this question on the Concrete5 site hasn't yet turned up an answer. Is anyone out there familiar enough with Concrete's login procedure that they have insight into this problem? I'm trying to avoid doing a clean install and spending my weekend recreating the site.

Comment: Is the site hosted on GoDaddy by any chance?

Comment: No, it's not. It's self-hosted, and there's a ton of other stuff on the server besides the Concrete install. I've been wondering if any of it could be interfering, but the first thing to eliminate is some error internal to Concrete itself.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess?

Comment: Check (or post) the latest Apache error logs, if possible.